# Finding a specific inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be some non-singular $n\times n$ matrix. I want to find the inverse of a following matrix
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} E & A \\ 0 & E\end{pmatrix},$$
where $E$ is the $n\times n$ unit matrix and $0$ is the $n\times n$ zero matrix. In this case $B$ is a $2n\times 2n$ matrix. Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?"  I might ask you the same...

Comment: What’s the inverse of the $2\times2$ matrix $\pmatrix{1&a\\0&1}$?

Comment: Write $B = I + N$ where $N$ is the upper right bit. Observe that $N^2 = 0$. Now $B^{-1} = (I + N)^{-1}$, which is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use block multiplication. $A$ doesn't have to be non-singular:
$$\begin{pmatrix}E&A\\0&E \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}E&-A\\0&E \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}E^2&-A+A\\0&E^2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}E&0\\0&E\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The resulting matrix is
$$
B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}E & -A\\0 & E\end{bmatrix}
$$

The operation $B^{-1} B$ must yield $E$, so:
$$
  B^{-1}B = \begin{bmatrix}E & 0\\ 0 & E\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let's say
$$
  B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}P & Q\\ R & S\end{bmatrix}
$$
The upper left quadrant of $B^{-1} B$ is given by
$$
PE+Q0 \stackrel{!}{=} E \quad \text{therefore} \quad P = E
$$
The lower left quadrant of $B^{-1} B$ is given by
$$
RE+S0 \stackrel{!}{=} 0  \quad \text{therefore} \quad R = 0
$$
The lower right quadrant of $B^{-1} B$ is given by
 $$
0A+SE \stackrel{!}{=} E\quad \text{therefore}  \quad S = E
$$
And the upper right quadrant of $B^{-1} B$ is given by
 $$
PA+QE = EA+QE \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \quad \text{so}  \quad Q = -A.
$$